# MySQL SUM not working correctly after JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have 2 tables that look like the following:

```
     TABLE 1              TABLE 2
user_id | date     accountID | date | hours
```

And I'm trying to add up the hours by the week. If I use the following statement I get the correct results:

```
SELECT
    SUM(hours) as totalHours
FROM
    hours
WHERE
    accountID = 244
    AND
    date >= '2014-02-02' and date < '2014-02-09'
GROUP BY
    accountID
```

But when I join the two tables I get a number like 336640 when it should be 12

```
SELECT
    SUM(hours) as totalHours
FROM
    hours
JOIN table1 ON
    user_id = accountID
WHERE
    accountID = 244
    AND
    date >= '2014-02-02' and date < '2014-02-09'
GROUP BY
    accountID
```

Does anyone know why this is?

EDIT: Turns out I just needed to add DISTINC, thanks!

Comment: Is this correct `date >= '2014-02-02' and date < '2014-02-09'` are not between parentethis ?

Comment: Putting them between parentheses didn't change anything

Comment: Can you explain what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: please provide some sample data too.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN operations usually generate more rows in the result table: join's result is a row for every possible pair of rows in the two joined tables that happens to meet the criterion selected in the ON clause.  If there are multiple rows in `table1` that match each row in `hours`, the result of your join will repeat hours.accountID and hours.hours many times. So, adding up the hours yields a high result.

Comment: How would I sum up the hours then if I need to access information from both tables?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the table you are joining to matches multiple rows in the first table.  These all get added together.

The solution is to do the aggregation in a subquery before doing the join:

```
select totalhours
from (SELECT SUM(hours) as totalHours
      FROM hours
      WHERE accountID = 244 AND
            date >= '2014-02-02' and date < '2014-02-09'
      GROUP BY accountID
     ) h join
     table1 t1
     on t1.user_id = h.accountID;
```

I suspect your actual query is more complicated.  For instance, `table1` is not referenced in this query so the join is only doing filtering/duplication of rows.  And the aggregation on `hours` is irrelevant when you are choosing only one account.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably be specifying `LEFT JOIN` to be sure that it won't eliminate rows that don't match.

Also, `date BETWEEN ? AND ?` is preferable to `date >= ? AND date < ?`.

Comment: Totally disagree with your suggestion about BETWEEN for dates. It makes no difference to performance, but it's almost impossible to get the end of the range right with BETWEEN when DATETIME values are in play.

Comment: What do you mean "impossible"? What problems are you having?

Comment: BETWEEN chooses an inclusive range [begin, end].  When you use that for datetime values as in `tstamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-02'` it leaves out all the values of tstamp that occur on the ending date range except those exactly at midnight.  The correct way of doing that is `tstamp >= '2014-01-01' AND tstamp < '2014-01-03'`. Note the use of `<` instead of `<=` in the end of that range. BETWEEN doesn't do that.

Comment: I strong agree with Ollie Jones. The `>=`/`<` is the preferred method of comparing dates (sometimes I'm lazy, but that is the best way).